# How to sort a list with sort function in python with less time complexity?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I want to sort this list a = [31415926535897932384626433832795, 1, 3, 10, 3, 5]. To reduce time complexity I want to first check whether the 2 elements are of same length or not. If both are of not same length I will swap them according to their length otherwise I will check which number is bigger and swap them. I want to implement this using `.sort()` function which have a parameter called `key`. I can use `a.sort(key=len)` but it will only work for the test cases with different length inputs. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: By length, do you mean the number of digits?

Comment: yes by length means no. of digits

Comment: The number of digits would require converting them to a string.  This will be an inherently slower operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are using `sort()` in Python, you can provide a function or anonymous (`lambda`) function to it as a basis for sorting.

In this case, you can use `lambda x` where `x` are the elements in `a`.

Subsequently, providing a tuple as a return result in the function allows the `sort` to prioritize in sorting, thus what you need is this:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x: (len(str(x)), x))
```

In the above code, `a` sorts first by `len(str(x))` then by the value of `x`

Edit: Added explanation

Comment: Can you please explain it. It would be better for us to learn.

Comment: How is this different from `a.sort()`?

Comment: No, by using normal .sort() I got timeout. But by using this I didn't.

Comment: How long is this list for which you get the timeouts and how big are the numbers?

Comment: what is the meaning of that lambda expression?

Comment: The constraints of my problem are 1 <= N = 2x10^5 and
1 <= a[i] <= 10^(10^6)

Comment: lambda acts like a function parameter and can take any number of arguments.

Comment: Code only answers are generally disfavored here — place edit your answer and explain what it's doing.

Comment: @ChallaSaiBhanuTeja I've edited my answer to add an explanation, sorry for the delay, posted the answer in a rush ytd and have been busy since.

Comment: @martineau sorry for the delay, I've added an explanation